# Running XOR encryption in a loop with str.replace doesn't change some characters

Tags: python, string, loops, encryption, str-replace

I'm trying to encrypt a text and then decrypt it using XOR. It changes most of the letters, but it skips some. When I change the "key" it skips the same letters. If I try another text it also skips some letters but at different places.

I tried to change a letter in the text:
"there is something wrong with my code"
"îòere ós sõmeîòóng wrõng wóîò mã ùõþe"

So it won't encrypt the letter "e" but when I change one "e" to "X" it works and encrypts the letter "e".

```
text = "there is something wrong with my code"
key = 154
print(key)
längd = (len(text))
for a in range(0,längd):
    b = ord(text[a])
    ny = b ^ key
    ny2 = chr(ny)
    text = text.replace(text[a],ny2)

print(text)
for a in range(0,längd):
    b = ord(text[a])
    ny = b ^ key
    ny2 = chr(ny)
    text = text.replace(text[a], ny2)

print(text)
```

If I try `key = 153` I get `"íñere ðs sömeíñðng wröng wðíñ mà úöýe"`.
If I try `key = 154` I get `"îòere ós sõmeîòóng wrõng wóîò mã ùõþe"`.

As you can see it doesn't change the letters "e,r,n,g,w,m".

Comment: Debugging tip: print `text` at every iteration of your for loop. It should be pretty clear what's going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the characters that are not changing when you run the loop are the characters that occur an even number of times in your string. The same XOR operation is used to both encrypt and decrypt the characters because XORing a number with another number twice gives the same number. What you are missing is the fact that Python's [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) replaces *all* occurrences of the first string with the second string. When you encounter the first 'e', all 'e's in the string are replaced with `key ^ ord('e')` not only the one you have just encountered. Other characters like 't' are also getting XORed more than once, but you don't notice them because XORing with a number 3 times is the same as XORing 1 time.

To iterate and operate on characters more easily, you should use a mutable sequence type like [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#func-bytearray):

```py
text = "there is something wrong with my code"
key = 154
print(key)
ba = bytearray(text, "latin_1")

for i in range(0, len(ba)):
    ba[i] = ba[i] ^ key

print(ba.decode("latin_1"))

for i in range(0, len(ba)):
    ba[i] = ba[i] ^ key

print(ba.decode("latin_1"))
```